# BackgroundSubtractor incorrect type when using via dictionary and multiprocessing

Tags: python, opencv, python-multiprocessing

The following is a simplified version of my program:

```
import cv2
import multiprocessing
import numpy
import copy
import time


def f(d, img):
    t0 = d[1]
    print("before")
    print(type(t0))
    Bg_sub_img = t0.apply(img,learningRate=0.1)
    print("after")



t0 = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG(history=20)
d = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()
#d = {}
#d[1] = copy.deepcopy(t0)
d[1] = t0
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)
print(type(t0))
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(d,img))
p.start()
time.sleep(10)
p.join()
```

which results in the following output:

```
<type 'cv2.bgsegm_BackgroundSubtractorMOG'>
before
<type 'cv2.bgsegm_BackgroundSubtractorMOG'>
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "amrutha.py", line 12, in f
    Bg_sub_img = t0.apply(img,learningRate=0.1)
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'BackgroundSubtractor' or its derivative)
```

If you try to run the program as just a regular funciton, without multiprocessing, it works ok. However, if instead of directly taking the variable t0, I perform a deepcopy of it (even when using it as a regular function and not running in a process), I get the same error.

If I try to just pass the variable (not the dictionary) in multiprocessing, its works ok too.

Not sure why thats the case. And when using it in a separate process, does it copy the object when passing it via a dicitonary? And which is perhaps the reason why it fails in a multiprocessing function?

FYI:
**Ubuntu 16.04
Python 2.7
OpenCV: 3.4.0**

Comment: You're only launching a single process so multiprocessing is pointless here. It only does something when you have multiple processes

Comment: @roganjosh As stated in the question, its a simplification of the program. The actual program has multiple consumer processes running which use the apply function. I've reduced the program to just highlight the error observed.